# Guess That Restaurant!

Tags: visual, rebus

Can you guess these five popular restaurant names?

[image]

Comment: You made me hungry ...

Comment: haha @kanchirck

Comment: Some of these might be a little U.S. centric. And by "a little" I mean that if anyone accustomed to sane units of measurement has ever heard of #4, it's only because of Brad's wife.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

1.

> McDonald's (Mike + Donald + s)

2.

> Papa John's (a dad + long johns - long)

3.

> Panera Bread (pan + air + ahhh, br + red)

4.

> Cracker Barrel (crack + err, barrel)

5.

> Popeyes (popping a bubble + multiple "i"s)

Comment: Those are correct! :)

Comment: Just beat me to 5 :)

Comment: I just got 2 I think though if you check my answer, you were close :)

Comment: @BeastlyGerbil: yeah, just got it too. Not sure how I missed it at first.

Comment: Good teamwork! :D

Answer (score 3):

Partial answer:

2:

> Papa johns: Papa + Long Johns - long

4:

> Cracker Barrel: Crack + er (to err is human) + Barrel

1, 3, and 5 were solved by gnovice

Comment: That is correct! :)